# Editable type but check if value is exists in list after update

Tags: c#, list

Let's assume that we have a SimpleClass class and another class that has a closed field of a list of values of a simple class:

```
public class TestClass
{
    private List<SimpleClass> _simpleClassList;

    public void Add(SimpleClass s)
    {
        if(_simpleClassList.Any(x=>x==s))
            return;
        _simpleClassList.Add(s);
    }
    public SimpleClass this[int index]
    {
        get => _simpleClassList[index];
        set
        {
            var curS = _simpleClassList[index];
            if (curS == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _simpleClassList[index] = value;
        }
    }
    public List<SimpleClass> SimpleClassList => _simpleClassList;
}

public class SimpleClass
{
    public string Porp1 { get; set; }
    public string Porp2 { get; set; }
    public static bool operator ==(SimpleClass left, SimpleClass right)
    {
        if (left is null && right is null) return true;
        if (left is null) return false;
        if (right is null) return false;

        return left.Porp1 == right.Porp1 && left.Porp2 == right.Porp2;
    }

    public static bool operator !=(SimpleClass left, SimpleClass right)
    {
        if (left is null && right is null) return false;
        if (left is null) return true;
        if (right is null) return true;
        return left.Porp1 != right.Porp1 || left.Porp2 != right.Porp2;
    }
}
```

Is there any possible way to check that after editing prop, there is no other value with the same properties in the list:

```
var t = new TestClass();
        t.Add(new SimpleClass() { Porp1 = "1", Porp2 = "1" });
        t.Add(new SimpleClass() { Porp1 = "1", Porp2 = "2" });
        t.Add(new SimpleClass() { Porp1 = "1", Porp2 = "3" });
        t.Add(new SimpleClass() { Porp1 = "1", Porp2 = "4" });

        var ft = t[0];
        ft.Porp2 = "2"; //Throw exception because we already have another element (index=2) with the same values prop1="1" and prop2="2"
```

Comment: Implement `IEquatable<SimpleClass>` and check via `list.Contains(target)`. Also rewrite your `==` and `!=` via `IEquatable.Equals`.

Comment: Seems like the incorrect pattern to me.... but you could add an internal property which gets assigned when the element is added to the list in the Add method... something like s.ContainingList = _simpleClassList... then in the setters use that to check if the list already contains that value.  But then again it just feels wrong. You might need to use a different pattern... maybe if you tell us more about the actual project

Comment: Side note: I suggest change `set` to `init` for both `Porp1` and `Porp2` properties in order not allowing change them when `SimpleClass` is added to the list.

Comment: Technically, you can check by using Linq: `bool valid = t.SimpleClassList.GroupBy(item => (item.Porp1, item.Porp2)).All(group => group.Count() == 1);`